# Tensorflow: split_v with variable num_splits

Tags: tensorflow

I am wondering if the same holds for `tf.split_v()` as `tf.split()`.

According to the documentation `split_v` also accepts a Tensor as second argument.

However, when I try this code

```
batch_size_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, name='BatchSize')
seq_length_ph = tf.placeholder(dtype = tf.int32, name='SeqLength')
input_data = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[50, 25, 10])


inputs = tf.split_v(input_data,seq_length_ph, 1) #tf.ones(seq_length_ph, tf.int32)
#inputs = [tf.squeeze(input_, [1]) for input_ in inputs]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    [out] = sess.run([inputs],feed_dict = {batch_size_ph: 50,
                                           seq_length_ph: 25,
                                           input_data: np.random.rand(50,25,10)})

print out
print len(out)
print out[0].shape
```

The error is

> NameError: global name 'value_shape' is not defined

Is this possible or not?

Comment: Where is `value_shape`? I'm not getting the same error

Comment: Tensorflow 0.12 is needed for this